# Java RMI: stopping a Thread running on the client machine

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi, interrupt

Suppose I have an `RMI` Client-Server application. Clients connect to the Server and at some point the Server starts a task. During the task Clients are doing some work, but at some other moment the Server must interrupt this work without letting the Clients finish it. Clients are implemented as Threads and the simplest solution looks like calling `thread.interrupt()`, but this does not work in `RMI`. Is there any other method or some workaround to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot think of a solution that can control/manage remote threads. The best approach would be to let the client listen to 'interrupt' messages...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a two-way remoting scheme in which, when a client performs the lookup for the server remote object and creates the local instance, it calls a method by which it passes a remote object of its own to the server. Then, when the server has finished its task, it can notify the client by calling a method in the remote object received from the client.

Comment: This seems probably the simplest solution, unfortunately it does not work. I'm calling a finish() method on Client where it should interrupt itself, but it doesn't happen.